# safari browser showing table contents vertical but google chrome is showing horizontal . I want to safari to show table contents horizantal

Tags: css

Want to show table contents(text / hyperlink/ div contents) horizontal in safari browser but dont know how to fix it as in google chrome table contents are absolutely showing fine as horizontal

```
enter code here
<div class="itemFields">
        <table>
          <tbody><tr>
            <td class="label" dir="ltr">Call Number</td>
            <td><div><a href="./query?match_1=PHRASE&amp;field_1=call_number&amp;term_1=PS169.F7+H3+1961&amp;theme=system" dir="ltr">PS169.F7 H3 1961</a></div></td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td class="label" dir="ltr">Publisher</td>
            <td><div><span dir="ltr">F. Ungar Pub. Co.</span></div></td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td class="label" dir="ltr">Year</td>
            <td><div><span dir="ltr">1961</span></div></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody></table>
      </div>




div.itemFields {
margin: 0;
margin-right: 15em;
}

.itemFields table tr td {
vertical-align: top;
}

.itemFields table tr td {
padding: 0;
}

.itemFields table tr td.label {
padding-right: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.itemFields table tr td div {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

.itemFields table tr td div a,
.itemFields table tr td div span {
display: inline;
}
```

this itemFields class content is showing contents of it vertical in safari browser

Comment: Could you provide code or link ?

Comment: i have searched on google regarding this and found that safari is a webkit browser and we have to set some other properties of webkit but don't know what properties to set as its working fine in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code ! You have to need reset code also better if you use bootstrap............. This code just simple *HTML5 Table* format & Style. You can change table width **960px** & more..........

```html
<div class="itemFields">
  <table width="960px" align="center" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="label" dir="ltr">Call Number</td>
        <td>
          <div><a href="./query?match_1=PHRASE&amp;field_1=call_number&amp;term_1=PS169.F7+H3+1961&amp;theme=system" dir="ltr">PS169.F7 H3 1961</a></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label" dir="ltr">Publisher</td>
        <td>
          <div><span dir="ltr">F. Ungar Pub. Co.</span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label" dir="ltr">Year</td>
        <td>
          <div><span dir="ltr">1961</span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesnt fix my issue . Actually this is running fine in chrome but in safari there is problem in displaying contents of table data as vertical of itemFields class

Comment: I added screenshot for safari ! please add how you want to show in safari

Comment: this is what i want to display in safari browser  https://imageshack.com/i/poFNMdeJp

Comment: After making changes to table i.e setting width="960px" and align="center" text and that hyperlink is still vertical which you have shown in your screenshot

Comment: If the site is live Please give me a link! I will take care rest of the problem or you can send source code to me

Comment: Vertical Means top to bottom but its sill show as your provided screenshot

Comment: please open it in chrome as well as in safari you will understand my problem,then